# How to give background colour for notification in Cordova(ionic v1 framework)

Tags: cordova, notifications, background-color, localnotification, ionic-v1

I developing hybrid application and using Cordova(ionic v1 framework).I am able to show local notification. But I want to change title, message colour and background colour of notification. I have seen coloured notification on other apps. Can we customize notification design? And I want show image also. Is it possible in Cordova( ionic v1)
I have referred following code for local notification.

```
 cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
      id: i,
      title: ' Alerts ',
       message: messagefield,
       at: notificationTime, // firstAt and at properties must be an IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamp
       every: 'day', // this also could be minutes i.e. 25 (int)
     });
```

Comment: If you get any solution means please share this. I'm also looking help on this

Comment: Yes I have implemented color notification. But this is achieved by implementing color notification in android(There no any way for colour notificaton in cordova) and merged notification call with cordova file.

Comment: I handled all the notification in android (MyFirebaseMessagingService.java).